# access local repository file instead of tfs file

Tags: tfs

We have a development server that is running TFS 2010, it is working fine however we have a bit of issue:

when person X take the latest and build the app , it get checkout abc.csproj application and due to that another person can't take the latest and it shows the error message as.

[image]

Here I'm looking for, whenever we modify any changes locally (pages) it should not get checked out & lock by TFS, only in their local repository it changes.

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two places you may need to change TFS to allow multiple check-outs.

1. In Visual Studio, use the "Team" menu, then "Team Project Settings", then "Source Control..." and ensure "Enable multiple check-out" is checked.
2. In Visual Studio, use the "Team" menu, then "Team Project Collection Settings", then "Source Control..." and ensure that if "csproj" is listed there, it has "File Merging" set to "Enabled".

Comment: @kiran - no problems - in the spirit of Stack Overflow, would you mind "accepting" this answer - it show's other people when they search? :)